# TypeError: Class constructor Document cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am working on a project(Next.js version 8.1.0) and I want to upgrade to version 9.2. I changed Next.js version to 9.2 and I am having this issue:

> TypeError: Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'
> at new MyApp (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_app.js:4384:191)
> at processChild (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2995:14)
> at resolve (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
> at renderToString (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
> at render (/home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:81:16)
> at renderPage (/home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:346:16)
> at Object.ctx.renderPage (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:2266:26)
> at Function.getInitialProps (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:1515:19)
> at _callee$ (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:2282:77)
> at tryCatch (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:428:40)
> at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:654:22)
> at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:480:21)
> at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:124:24)
> at _next (/home/node/app/src/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:146:9)

Here is my next.config.js:

```
    const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const { resolve } = require('path');

let baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL;
baseUrl = baseUrl && baseUrl.length && '/' !== baseUrl ? baseUrl : '';

module.exports = withSass({
  transpileModules: ['file-type'],
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            configFile: resolve('babel.config.js'),
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
            transpileOnly: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /node_modules\/file-type/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            configFile: resolve('babel.config.js'),
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(file-type))/,
            include: /node_modules\/file-type/,
            sourceType: 'unambiguous',
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts');
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.tsx');
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.jsx');
    /* if (options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({ tsconfig: resolve('./tsconfig.json') }));
    } */

    return config;
  },
  pageExtensions: ['jsx', 'tsx'],
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
  },
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    includePaths: [resolve('src/scss')],
  },
  webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
    if (process.env.ENABLE_WATCH_POLL) {
      const watchOptions = {
        poll: true,
        aggregateTimeout: 500,
        ignored: [
          '.git/**',
          'src/.next/**',
          '**/__tests__/**',
          '.scannerwork/**',
          'cypress/**',
          'doc/**',
          'node_modules/**',
          'src/static/**',
        ],
      };
      return { ...config, watch: true, watchOptions };
    }
    return config;
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    env: process.env.APP_ENV,
    nodeEnv: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    apiProxy: process.env.API_PROXY,
    subscriptionKey: process.env.OCP_APIM_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
    apiEndpoint: process.env.API_ENDPOINT,
    serverPort: process.env.SERVER_PORT,
    gmapApiendpoint: process.env.GMAP_API_KEY,
    gigyaApiKey: process.env.GIGYA_API_KEY,
    gigyaDatacenter: process.env.GIGYA_DATACENTER,
    templateReimbursementLink: process.env.TEMPLATE_REIMBURSEMENT_LINK,
    reimbursementStatusLink: process.env.REIMBURSEMENT_STATUS_LINK,
    gtmId: process.env.GTM_ID,
    captchaSiteKey: process.env.CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
    baseUrl,
    redisPort: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    redisHost: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    redisPassword: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  },
});
```

Comment: and did you invoke `MyApp` with the `new`-keyword? E.g. `const app = new MyApp();`?

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment in the GitHub issue you also have commented on](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9000#issuecomment-540064962) it says to remove `babel-loader` from your `next.config.js`, as Next.js already includes this.